# Grails lazy fetch in bidirectional one-to-many

Tags: grails, one-to-many, lazy-evaluation

i've confused by lazy initialized collections in a **bidirectional one-to-many** relation,

i've two domains Module and Rule, there is a bidirectional otm between them

```
Class Module{
..
static hasMany = [providedRules : Rule]
..
}

Class Rule{
..
static belongsTo = [module : Module]
..
}
```

a simple method for testing:

```
def module = Module.get(id)
module.providedRules.each{
println it.description // i expected a query to Rule table for each iteration
}
```

**i would expect a query for each access to "description" property, but i didn't see any queries for iterations.**

have you any ideas ?

thanks

Comment: so, it isn't. What was your question again?

Comment: but by default, a collection should be lazy-initialized ...

Comment: it is, till you explicitly load it

Comment: but i got a real-class instance collection instead of a proxy collection .

Comment: you might be getting a proxy-collection enhanced on-the-fly with groovy MP. Can you describe your PROBLEM, instead of your OBSERVATIONS or INSIGHTS?

Comment: i just modified my question :)

Comment: again, you can call for help if you see a `PROBLEM`. meaning, that you either get an exception, or no results, or results you were not expecting.

Comment: yes, i expected a extra query for each iteration, but i did't see any queries in loop.

Comment: how are you monitoring the sql queries? over `hibernate.show_sql=true`?

Comment: in config.groovy   debug 'org.hibernate.SQL' , i also configured an appender for it (a log file)

Comment: I was usually using the following lines in DataSource.groovy: `hibernate{ show_sql = true }`

Answer (score 0):

Add logging like this and see what happens in logs:

```
datasource {
...
logSql = true
...
}
```

See also [fetching](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#fetching) in docs
**Update:**
Checked in grails. Remove belongsTo from Rule and it works like you want. Lokks like if bidirectional mapping, it loads not a proxy but full object.

Comment: I think you don't understand...collection lazily loaded is collection of proxy object, each proxy has a ID value, but other fields still NULL until you access to it explicitly.

Comment: if you have a unidirectional one to many : a join table is used, your collection loaded by one query is a proxies collection. if you want to load real object to replace each proxy, you need a extra query for each proxy.

Comment: if you have a bidirectional one to many, you can load entire collection of real object by using "join" fetch.